# How to make Wordpress Post type featured?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on Featured wordpress post on post type , how to make it featured and when the featured is selected the post must show on the top of the list

I have tried by updating meta_key on event but now I want to make or assign that featured post on the top of the list. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try this link, that would solve your problem.
https://smallenvelop.com/how-to-create-featured-posts-in-wordpress/

Comment: <?php
 $postdata = array();
 if ( have_posts() ) {
  while ( have_posts() ) {
   the_post();
   $convert    = $post_object->convert( $post );
   $postdata[] = $convert;
   get_template_part( 'template/profile', 'item' );
  }
 }
 ?>